# Failing to Convert Files from CSV to Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv, character-encoding

Attempting to convert a folder list of csv files to excel. Unfortunately most of them do not work and I also get following errors. When I do the same via excel front end, it works fine to save them from csv. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
import os
import glob
import csv
import openpyxl # from https://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/ or PyPI (e.g. via pip)

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
            for c, val in enumerate(row, start=1):
                ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = val
    wb.save(csvfile + '.xlsx')
```

Get the following errors:

> (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\test\Documents\ConvertCSVtoXLSX\2007+.py", line 14, in 
>       ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = val
>
> File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 272, in value
>       self._bind_value(value)
>
> File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 229, in _bind_value
>       value = self.check_string(value)
>
> File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 180, in check_string
>       value = unicode(value, self.encoding)
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 30: invalid start byte

Comment: Try using `'r'` instead of `'rb'`

Comment: I have tried this, seems like it still does not work. I also noticed that the file size are different when converting using the script vs saving the file directly using excel16. Could this be down to way the script is limited

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pyopenxl expects that it will receive data encoded as UTF-8, but the data you are passing it has some other encoding - probably one of the Windows cp* codepages.  You can determine the system's default encoding by calling [locale.getpreferredencoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding).  Let's assume it's `cp1252`.

In the traceback, we can see that this is the failing line:

```
unicode(value, self.encoding)
```

resulting in this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 30: invalid start byte
```

pyopenxl is trying to decode the value it receives from UTF-8, and failing; we can work round this by re-encoding the value before passing it to pyopenxl.

```
for c, val in enumerate(row, start=1):
    fixed_val = unicode(val, 'cp1252').encode('utf-8')
    ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = fixed_val
```

If it's possible that some of your files are encoded as UTF-8 and some are encoded in your system's default encoding, you may need to wrap the original assignment in a try/except block

```
for c, val in enumerate(row, start=1):
    try:
        ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = val
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        fixed_val = unicode(val, 'cp1252').encode('utf-8')
        ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = fixed_val
```